# How to conditionally change screenOptions for different react native screens in the same Navigator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I have a Navigator with 2 screens. In one of them I want to show the `headerRight` component and in the other screen, I don't want to show the `headerRight` component.

My Navigation looks like this:

```js
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ 
        headerShown: true, 
        headerRight: () => <Switch /> // conitionally change this
      }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Vocabulary" component={bottomNavigator} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Definition" component={Definition}  />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

- Do I render `headerRight` conditionally based on what screen is visible?
- Do I have multiple navigators?
- Do I configure it within the rendered compnent (i.e. `Definition`)?

Comment: you can also check condition inside switch. just return null if you don't want to show anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setOptions({
      headerRight: <Switch />
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify an option for a particular screen and not for all screens, then specify it in the `option` of the desired screen instead of in `screenOptions`:

```js
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
      headerShown: true
    }}
  >
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Vocabulary"
      component={bottomNavigator}
      options={{
        // Show only for Vocabulary screen
        headerRight: () => <Switch />
      }}
    />
    <Stack.Screen name="Definition" component={Definition} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

If you don't want an option to apply to all screens in a navigator, don't specify it in `screenOptions` which is applies to all screens. Multiple navigators for it seem overkill.

More details https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options